# Monitor not Detected so I have a resolution problem

Tags: resolution, monitor

I installed Ubuntu in an Old PC and the problem is that Ubuntu is unable to detect my monitor which is **Samsung SyncMaster 591s** . When I go to **System -> Preferences -> Monitor** , There is no option to change the resolution and it is set to `800 * 600` .
Which looks utterly ugly.

**Here is a screenshot**
[image]

There are no options in **Resolution, Refresh rate, Rotation** listed in the Monitor preferences other than shown in the screenshot.

I don't have any Graphic Card installed.

Its a dual boot system with windows xp and, XP has perfectly fine resolution.
Here is the output of `lspci` , if it helps

```
varun@varun-desktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 82)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL (ICH4/ICH4-L) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
01:01.0 Modem: PCTel Inc HSP56 MicroModem (rev 04)
01:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
varun@varun-desktop:~$
```

PS: I looked into older questions regarding this issue on AU but they don't seem to help.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?

Comment: @jrg yes, the issue still persists in Oneiric too.

Comment: @Gauav If you could link to the other questions that you've used that'd be great. :)

Comment: @jrg Sorry, I don't remember anymore which questions I looked into. Maybe I looked up http://askubuntu.com/search?q=monitor+resolution

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closeure. =)

Comment: @BlueXrider No. I'm no more in contact with the person I asked this question for. Feel free to close it if required :)